# Model validation not working with Razor Page & PageModel

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Page that has a tag to print out an error message, and also prints the walue of `ModelState.IsValid`.

```razor
@page
@model IndexModel

<form asp-page="Index" method="get">
    <input asp-for="Message"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Message"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<p>ModelState.IsValid = @Model.ModelIsValid</p>
```

The PageModel is annotated with a regex requirement:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [FromQuery]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]*$")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool ModelIsValid { get; private set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        ModelIsValid = ModelState.IsValid;
    }
}
```

The model is always valid though, regardless of what I set the `Message` to or don't add it at all.

**NB** `Message` is correctly populated.

**NB 2** Neither adding `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` or replacing `[FromQuery]` with `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]` changes the behaviour.

Why aren't my annotations being effective?

I've shared the full project here:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6otEu-6FtC2VFoLNCTDydGUSIR

Comment: I reproduced your issue in .NET Core 2.1 and found `ModelState.IsValid` returns true on the first load, but when submitting non-letters e.g. `12345` or even gibberish symbols e.g. `$&%*^@` the page responded with this message: `The field Message must match the regular expression '^[A-Za-z]*$'` and `ModelState.IsValid` returns false. Have you read [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6891) already?

Comment: Thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto.  That's exactly the issue!  I added `.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);` to the `StartUp` and things work now.  Would you like to add it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is to change

`services.AddMvc();`

to

`services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);`

in `Startup.cs`

As per https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6790 this will allow your application to enable this behaviour.